# Place two cells under a header with the colspan of 1

Tags: html, css

I am struggling to put the cells containing { Lazy, Dog, Then, It } under the same header (with a colspan of 1)

I've tried creating div tags within my cell, creating 2 cells, and all the possible widths and colspan combinations I can think of.

[image]

Using div tags and CSS I can get Lazy and Dog under the header, but they are not individual cells.

[image]

```
    <html>
<head>
<style>

        table,td,tr,th{
            border: 1px solid black;
            }


            .lazy {
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            }

            .dog {
            float: right;
            width: 50%;
            }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
            <tr>
                <th>Quick</th>
                <th>brown fox</th>
                <th>jumps</th>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td rowspan=3>over the</td>
                <td><div class="lazy">lazy</div> <div class="dog">dog</div></td>
                <td>and</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>then</td>
                <td>it</td>
                <td>fall</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan=2> prey to a lion </td>
            </tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `colspan="2"` to `<th>brown fox</th>`

you don't have to put div inside `<td>` to separate data

then edit your `<td colspan=2> prey to a lion </td>`

to `<td colspan="3"> prey to a lion </td>`

here is the working fiddle, hope it helped you

https://jsfiddle.net/LLa90017/1/

Answer (score 1):

Easy as pie as follows:

```css
        table, td, tr, th {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }


        .lazy {
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
        }

        .dog {
            float: right;
            width: 50%;
        }
```

```html
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Quick</th>
            <th colspan="2">brown fox</th>
            <th>jumps</th>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td rowspan=3>over the</td>
            <td>lazy</td> 
            <td>dog</td>
            <td>and</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>then</td>
            <td>it</td>
            <td>fall</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan=3> prey to a lion </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```